# Linker Error with SoundCloud iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, soundcloud

I am trying to link the frameworks needed for SoundCloud SDK based on this tutorial https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#installation

It tells you to link libSoundCloudAPI.a, libSoundCloudUI.a, etc and they appear in my workspace folder when I add them but after I add them they appear red and Xcode cannot find them. When I build obviously I get a Mach -O Linker Error because Xcode cannot locate these files. I've searched through the frameworks as well and couldn't find them.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid SoundCloud decided not to maintain anymore this library, so I decided to create my own one and publish it. Maybe it can help you.

[ABMSoundCloudAPI on Github](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)

Comment: do you have any instructions for how to make calls to this API like the SoundCloud one? Thanks

Comment: Yes, inside of the project there is a folder called `Example`. There you can find an app doing almost every available request.